# Why is using 700 permission for directories not enough?

Tags: apache

Why is 700 permission for directories not working in Apache (and maybe other web servers)?

We receive the **403 Forbidden** status error code.

I think 700 is enough when we are using `SUphp`, so that the process owner is the same of the files' or directories' owner.

Comment: Who does the directory belong to?

Comment: The owner of the directory is the same as the owner of the file accessing the directory ..

Comment: So the directory belongs to the Apache user? `700` allows access only to the owner of the file, no one else

Comment: With 700 permissions, the process that is trying to access the file has to be running under the same user as the owner of the directory/file in question. This is different than the file the process is accessing.

Comment: The uid of the php file that accessing the directory is the same as owner id the directory

Comment: @baraboom
when we use suPHP apache makes the current process UID the same as the owner of the file should be parsed.
Let's assume that i requested file 'f.php' that owned by user 'x' 
and that file will access the a directory owned by 'x' too
and as i mentioned above apache uses suPHP module 
so 700 is enough !

Comment: The owner of the php file does not matter.  A php file, or any other script, does not access a directory.   It is just a text file. Some other executable interprets it.... usually apache through an apache module.

Comment: @Biz, it sounded like you were not using suphp in this case but if that is the case, you must have another issue... either the directory is nested inside of another directory with incorrect permissions or you have something in your httpd.conf that is preventing access. It's always a good idea to check the apache error log in these cases to help narrow it down. Good luck.

Comment: @baraboom The docs at http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG certainly hint that it won't work if not set up precisely.  They need to get the error reporting as verbose as possible so they can identify what exactly is failing,

Comment: Directories, in my experience, have to have at least group-execute and maybe world-execute. So one of 0710, 0711, 0750, 0751, or 0755 on those directories should do it. 0755 will definitely do it.

Comment: @ Pete Wilson: 
That's what i think too ...

Comment: @Pete Wilson: classical directories rights are better starting with a 2: i.e. 2750, 2770, 2775, etc. The 2 make new files created in the directory to re-use user and group of the directory. And as stated in karmakaze response the user running the web servioce as to have an execute right, either by the user or by the group, to enter the directory and list files in it.

Answer (score 1):

Directories can never be 'executed' like programs, as such the 'x' bit of the permissions for directories has the meaning that it can be 'entered' that is made the current directory. So the effective user must have 'x' permission either by user, group, or other in order to enter into it.